# returning a string to a textfield

Tags: java

i have a program which does this. A string is inputted by the user is stored as a String in an arraylist. When the user presses the up arrow, the most recently entered command is shown in the JTextField. Further presses of the up arrow will display other commands in the JTextField,ordered by the most recently entered until there are no more commands to display or the user stops.

Storing the string in the arraylist is working fine the only issue that i've got is with the Jtextfield only one command is shown in it when i press the up arrow even if i have typed multiple commands Can any body help below is the code for when the up arrow is pressed.

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < history.list.size(); i++)
            {
                field.setText(history.list.get(i));
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: don't loop .check is index exit and show it

Comment: "When the user presses the up arrow, the most recently entered command is shown in the JTextField. Further presses of the up arrow will display other commands in the JTextField,ordered by the most recently entered until there are no more commands to display or the user stops."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in this block of codes:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < history.list.size(); i++)
        {
            field.setText(history.list.get(i));
        }
```

This makes the `field` to always display the last element from your history list. Because it will iterate the entire list, hence it will always update the `field` with the last element from your list.

To solve the problem, you can keep a `index` variable. When key is pressed, update the index accordingly. Then set field accordingly:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) 
{
    index = (index + 1)% history.list.size();  //Ensure it stays within bounds
    field.setText(history.list.get(index));
}
else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) 
{
    index = Math.max(0, index - 1);            //Ensure it stays within bounds
    field.setText(history.list.get(index));
}
```

Comment: i tried earlier using something like your method above.. but it is giving me the last command aswell, i also initialized my int index to 0

Comment: @Zajra11 Then there must be some other parts of your codes affecting the result. You will have to show more codes or rather a [mcve].

Comment: solved thanks for your help i was intializing the index in the wrong class/method.

Comment: @Zajra11 Glad to help